# How to deal with one clock input at the IC when most crystals and oscillators have two pins?

Tags: pcb

I am having trouble in figuring out how to deal with an IC that only has a single input for the sleep clock. Does one pin of the clock go into the IC and the other to ground, or does configuration vary from device to device?

[image: Single Input clock]

[Datasheet for reference](https://www.lairdconnect.com/documentation/datasheet-sterling-lwb5-0)

Comment: A clock input is not the same thing as an oscillator input just like a crystal (an oscillator) is not the same thing as a clock IC that outright generates a clock square wave. Oscillator and clock are not interchangeable terms.

Comment: You use a clock generator (IC) which is connected to the oscillator on one side and is outputting a clock pulse on the other. Or generate it by some other means.

Comment: The title of your question is wrong - oscillators do not (typically) have 2 pins.

Comment: @DKNguyen Thanks for clarifying! I can be forgetful and clump components together in terms of broad functionality

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks for you suggestion Eugene! This does look to be a good option for the problem but due to space constraints, I will have to look into an alternative method of generation.

Comment: @brhans Seems like I need to develop my understanding with this subject! Thanks for pointing out my misconceptions as now I can work to improve on that!

Comment: I believe 32kHz MeMS clock ICs exist. Like SOT-23 sized. If you can't fit that you probably can't fit anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't confuse for example MCU crystals for oscillators. The crystal is part of the oscillator circuit, see for example this (source: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierce_oscillator)<sup>1)</sup>)

[image]

On a typical MCU, the U1 part is internal and the rest of the components need to be provided by the PCB designer. Which is why MCUs have two pins for this. Some MCUs have an actual clock output as a separate 3rd pin.

So what you need to do is to provide a crystal *oscillator* with everything (except the caps) built-in and not just a crystal. They need supply & ground and give a single clock output, so typically 3 pins (or rather in practice 4 pins where one is dummy). The oscillator datasheet will state which cap values that are required. Connect the oscillator output to your IC's clock input and there you go.

---

<sup>1)</sup> By Original: Thann75 Vector: Omegatron - Own work based on:, CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=2188865